# How to restore vqmod cache in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, vqmod

I was trying to a tutorial on google how to disable a vqmod temporarily but something went wrong.

I created a folder inside the **vqmod > xml** and named it **"disabled"** then put my files there but when I'm about to put them all back where they're original was. It doesn't change anything, I even re-uploaded my website but it still look the same and I even tried to clear my browser's history but it's still the same.

Do you guys have any ideas what happened or what to do? It's messed up.

Comment: Try to remove files from `vqcache` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to following.

- Go to `vqmod > xml` and rename the xml's by adding an `_` at the
  end.(Then when you want to enable them back, rename the files back to
  `.xml`)
- also, Remove files from `vqmod > vqcache` directory.
- If you’re using any **caching extensions**. So, Go to your OpenCart dashboard
  and clear the website cache. Then reload your website.
- also, if, You are used OpenCart2. So, Go to **admin > Extensions >
  Modifications** and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner)
  for update the system. & then check it.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. I did what you suggested but nothing happens. On my Journal2 there's clear cache and it did nothing :(

Comment: if, You are used OpenCart2. So, Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system. & then check it.